# Been going around caulking the inside windows and ran into a bigger gap

Tags: caulking

I have been going around the replacing the old caulk where it was cracked on the insides of my windows.  I came across this window and it really opened up when scraping away the old caulk.  It's by far the biggest gap so far and I'm guessing needs more than just a re-caulk.  I stopped scraping after the first bit, got a little worried.  As you can see in the photos, the insullation is visible and the wall flexes quite a bit.

Photos:  https://ibb.co/album/hfDAOv

Is this a big issue or can I just fill it with a different product?  Would something like a foam backer rod work here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it has been there since the dry wall was mudded and not something new. I would not expect water damage to look like that. I don't know what is the reason for the wall flex or if it is excessive. More than likely it was either a poor fit of the dry wall during installation or these are newer windows that were narrower than the originals. I suggest filling in with 'hot' mud which is a chemical set dry wall mud that is fast setting and won't shrink and crack